onEdit function to clear range of cells
I need some help to create a simple trigger for my Google spreadsheet. What I'd like is to enter "clear" in cell D1 and have it triggers a script that clears all the cells in the range B2:D32.
So far I've got:
function ClearCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('All');
  sheet.getRange('B2:D32').clearContent();
}

I need help with the trigger when "clear" is entered in D1.

I appreciate the effort you made to improve your question.

You need to use the edit function if you want it to run automatically whenever the sheet is edited.
You can use the event object from onEdit to determine the name of the sheet.
You have the right idea with the line that clears the data.
Below I have adapted your script to use onEdit(e) and included a few additional conditions/tests you might find useful.

Updated Formula
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if ((sheet.getName() == "All") &&
      (e.range.getA1Notation() == "D1")
      && (e.value == "clear")) {

    sheet.getRange("B2:D32").clearContent();
  } 
} 

Explanation

onEdit(e) is a simple trigger that runs automatically when a value is changed in any cell in the spreadsheet.
e is the event object from the edit.
The sheet that was edited is retrieved using the event object's range and stored in the constant sheet
Several conditions are checked each joined by && so that once any one condition fails, the rest are ignored (they all must be true):

The first checks the sheet name matches All
The second checks the edited cell is D1
The last condition is that the cell value must be the word clear.


If all the conditions were met, the contents of range B2:D32 are cleared.

